# How to integrate a function given several other integrations?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

I am studying for an upcoming Calculus exam, and was hoping someone here could explain how to do the following.

\begin{align}
\int_1^9 f(x)\,\mathrm dx&=-1\\
\int_7^9 f(x)\,\mathrm dx&=5\\
\int_7^9 h(x)\,\mathrm dx&=4\\
\end{align}

What is value of the following integral:

$$
\int_1^7 f(x)\,\mathrm dx
$$

Comment: The information about $h(x)$ is completely irrelevant. I suppose part of the point of this question is for you to recognize that and ignore $h(x)$.

Comment: **Hint:** For $a < c < b$

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = \int_{a}^{c} f(x) dx + \int_{c}^{b} f(x) dx$$

Comment: Hint. If you imagine the graph of $f$ between 1 and 9 and think about those integrals as computing areas you might be able to see where @Mattos  's hint comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a,b,c$ be 3 numbers in the real line, such $a>c>b$, and $f(x): \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ continuous in $(a,b)$, we have
$$ \int_a^b f(x) dx =  \int_a^c f(x) dx + \int_c^b f(x) dx.$$

For your specific case, we have
$$ \int_1^9 f(x) dx =  \int_1^7 f(x) dx + \int_7^9 f(x) dx \implies\\ \int_1^7 f(x) dx =  \int_1^9 f(x) dx - \int_7^9 f(x) dx = -1 - 5 = -6.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_1^7f\,dx=\int_1^9f\,dx+\int_9^7f\,dx=\int_1^9f\,dx-\int_7^9f\,dx=-1-5=-6$$